# Как правильно типизировать функцию

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Есть функция:

```typescript
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

function setFieldError<T>(setState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>, fieldName: keyof T, value: T[ keyof T ][ "error" ])
{
    setState((prevState) => (
        {
            ...prevState,
            [ fieldName ]:
            {
                ...prevState[ fieldName ],
                error: value
            }
        }
    ));
}

export default setFieldError;
```

Я получаю ошибку:

> Тип ""error"" не может использоваться для индексации типа "T[keyof T]". ts(2536)

### Как ее использовать

Есть стэйт:

```typescript
interface IFieldsState
{
    field1: { value: string; error: boolean; };
    field2: { value: string; error: boolean; };
    field3: { value: string; error: boolean; };
    field4: { value: string; error: boolean; };
    field5: { value: string; error: boolean; };
    field6: { value: string; error: boolean; };
}

const initFieldsState: IFieldsState =
{
    field1: { value: "", error: false },
    field2: { value: "", error: false },
    field3: { value: "", error: false },
    field4: { value: "", error: false },
    field5: { value: "", error: false },
    field6: { value: "", error: false }
};

// ...

const [ fields, setFields ] = useState<IFieldsState>(initFieldsState);
```

Как я применяю функцию:

```typescript
setFieldError(setFields, "field1", false);
```

Comment: сейчас нет ограничений на `T` - поэтому ты можешь передать тип у которого не будет этого поля, поэтому и ошибка

Answer (score 1):

```
function setFieldError<T extends { [fieldName: string]: { error: boolean } }>(
  setState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>,
  fieldName: keyof T,
  value: T[keyof T]['error'],
) {
  setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [fieldName]: {
      ...prevState[fieldName],
      error: value,
    },
  }));
}

export default setFieldError;
```

Comment: Все бы конечно хорошо.. Если бы не одно но, error не везде будет boolean, именно поэтому мне необходимо было правильно типизировать ожидаемый `value`.

Comment: Ну сделайте `T extends { [fieldName: string]: { error: any } }`. Вам нужно победить `Тип ""error"" не может использоваться для индексации типа "T[keyof T]". ts(2536)` или еще что-то?

Comment: Если я поставлю Any, разве оно не будет игнорировать тип у определенного поля?